# Connect to Azure SQL Server through Azure VPN Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server, azure-vpn

I have an Azure SQL Server & Azure SQL Database, a virtual network with two subnets, a vm and an Azure VPN Gateway.

The VM is on Subnet1.

Azure VPN Gateway uses GatewaySubnet.

In the Azure SQL Server > Firewalls and virtual networks > I have added both subnets.

Now if I VPN into my virtual network, and connect to the VM, I can then use SSMS inside this VM to connect to the Azure SQL Server successfully.

If I try and connect to the Azure SQL Server from my laptop with the VPN connection established (So not through the VM), it will not let me connect.

I can see the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview#limitations) says Site-to-Site and Express route is not supported, but it does not say Point-to-Site is not supported, so would expect this to work.

Does anyone know if the documentation is wrong by not stating this as unsupported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you ever found an answer or a workaround, but I'm currently hitting the same roadblock.  I'm connecting to my P2S VPN OK and can access VM resources in the same subnet, but cannot access the Azure SQL server (or DB's) via SSMS on my laptop.

It looks like it's still not supported - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/da8da34a-ad48-43a4-a070-311036e23675/exposing-azure-sql-server-through-vpn-connection?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork.